# Proving necessity of a condition for minimum of a convex function

Tags: convex-optimization, constraints, subgradient

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function and $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex set. Consider the problem of minimizing 
 $f(x)$ subject to $x \in C$, and let $x^\star$ denote the solution to this minimization problem.   How can I prove that there exist no $g, z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the following equations
$$\begin{cases}f(y)\geq f(x^\star)+g^T(y-x^\star),~\forall y \in C\\
g^T(z-x^\star)<0\end{cases}$$
hold together
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find a contradiction if your assumptions that $x^*$ is a solution and there existed $g,z$ such that your equations held.

Consider 
$$f(x^*) \geq f(y) + g^T(x^*-y),\quad \forall y \in C \tag{1}$$
and
$$g^T(y-x^*) < 0 \tag{2}$$
Then we have $c := g^T(x^*-y) > 0$ so that by $(1)$, we have
$$f(x^*) \geq f(y) + c \tag{3} \iff f(x^*) - c \geq f(y)$$
which means that $y$ is a "better" point than $x^*$ because we have $f(y) < f(x^*)$ now.

Comment: Doesn't this only imply that $f(x^\star)\leq f(y)+k$, where $k=-c> 0$? So it is still possible $f(x^\star)<f(y)$

Comment: Oops, sorry, think you're right

Comment: About equation (1), you might have flipped a sign in the process. I think it should be $f(x^\star)\leq f(y)+g^T(x^\star-y)$, starting from the equation in the question. Then, the reasoning that follows does not hold.

Comment: The definition of convexity for functions requires every point to have a supporting hyperplane defined by its (sub)-gradient(s). That is, the graph lies above the tangents. So we can use this relationship at any $y\in C$, and in particular, we can use this relationship at $x^* \in C$ (where we're assuming that $g$ is a subgradient of $f$ at $y$ in $(1)$).

Comment: So, I think your reformulation of the original convexity constraint in your problem is valid, but it's looking at $g$ at $x^*$ vs at $y$ in $(1)$. Since the conditions is "there exists no $g$", we can look for the "right" $g$ which happens to be evaluated at $y$. Let me know if you buy this or if I've messed up! Btw, here's a nice link on [convexity](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~larry/=sml/convexopt.pdf)